# How should we tag "Bit.TRIP presents Runner 2: Legend of Rhythm Alien"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've created the tag [bit-trip-runner-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bit-trip-runner-2) because it's a lot easier to remember, but should we change it to make it more in line with the name?

For example, should we go with:

- [bit-trip-presents-runner2-legend-of-rhtyhm-alien](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bit-trip-presents-runner2-legend-of-rhtyhm-alien)
- [bit-trip-runner2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bit-trip-runner2)
- [bit-trip-runner2-lora](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bit-trip-runner2-lora)

Comment: [tag:bit-trip-presents-runner2-legend-of-rhtyhm-alien] is way too long for the tag limit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[runner2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/runner2) (no dash) is what we should be using. While being a sequel to Bit.Trip Runner, the game is not a Bit.Trip game itself - the collection of six games is over and done with; the game itself retains the core mechanics of the first game but very little of the Bit.Trip aesthetics.

- The official website is [runner2.com](http://www.runner2.com/)
- The official website title tag reads "Runner 2 Dev Blog", but the rest of the static site references it as "Runner2"
- "Runner2" is the link text about the game in the Games dropdown at developer website [gaijingames.com](http://gaijingames.com/)
- The full name of the game, as seen on Steam, has [no space between "Runner" and "2".](http://store.steampowered.com/app/218060/)
- The game is not part of [the Bit.Trip collection](http://www.bittripgame.com/).
- The developers speak consistently about "Runner2", rather than "Bit.Trip Runner 2"

Comment: people refer to it as bit trip runner 2 though

Comment: @Retrosaur That's why we have tag synonyms. "Bit Trip Runner 2" is *not* what the game is called.